# Shoehorning hierarchial data into ArcSDE for MS SQL Server?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, relationship-class

I've been tasked with creating a set of tables to store hierarchical data within an ArcSDE.

This is in reference to utility data, i.e, a set of valves, control panels, actuators, etc (each potentially having their own attributes) belong to a pump, the pump belongs to a process (also having its own attributes), which belongs to a pumpstation (which can have its own attributes) etc etc.

The only way I can think of to do this is to basically have a table for each asset (a table each for valves, control panels, actuators, pumps, process, pumpstation) and a relationship class for each one to link to the table higher up in the hierarchy for it, all the way to the top, and then a final relationship class to link the pump station table to an already existing pump station point feature class.

I've already googled some to find examples of using hierarchical data in ArcGIS and i'm not having much luck. Anyone have any suggestions if there's a better way of doing this?